# Returning local string-literal by char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, string-literals

I have a template function that will receive an enumerator and it will convert it into a C-style null-terminated string. I understand that this program has a logical error, as local variable of function is passed back as return value by reference. However, the program is executed with no errors or warnings (Visual Studio 17). Will this cause any undefined behaviours or memory leaks? When the str goes out of scope, does the copy of the address get returned and the pointer variable gets destroyed? Is this a good programming practice?

My other option that I can think of is creating a dynamic memory. For example, `const char* str = new char[size]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace Letter {
    enum class Letter {
        AP, // A+
        A,  // A
        BP, // B+
        B,  // B
        CP, // C+
        C,  // c
        DP, // D+
        D,  // D
        F   // F

    };

    template <typename T>
    const char* convertToStr(const T& t) {
        const char* str;

        switch (t) {
        case Letter::AP:
            return str = "A+";
        case Letter::A:
            return str = "A";
        case Letter::BP:
            return str = "B+";
        case Letter::B:
            return str = "B";
        case Letter::CP:
            return str = "C+";
        case Letter::C:
            return str = "C";
        case Letter::DP:
            return str = "D+";
        case Letter::D:
            return str = "D";
        case Letter::F:
            return str = "F";
        default:
            return str = "ERROR: unmatched grade";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you write `return str = "foo";` instead of `return "foo";`?

Comment: Consider to return `std::string_view` to preserve the compile-time string length information.

Answer (score 4):

The program is correct. The string literal has a lifetime of the whole program, so it is guaranteed to be always available.

However, the program is unnecessary verbose.

```
return str = "ERROR: unmatched grade";
```

is the same as

```
return "ERROR: unmatched grade";
```

but cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Another question, why doesn't it work for integers? By that I mean returning local integer pointer variables as a reference? Do other literals such as integer literals, floating literals last the entire program? Or does only character strings have a lifetime of the whole program

Comment: @sangminpark all literals have a lifetime of a program. But you can't have a pointer to floating point literal or integer literal, so I am not sure what you are referring to. May be you need to ask a separate question and provide some code example.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe since string literals have static storage duration - meaning they exists for the lifetime of the program.

You can simply return the string literal

```
 return "D+";
```

Even if you did assign it to a local variable and returned that(shown a bit more explicitly here:)

```
str = "D+";
return str;
```

it will be safe, that string literal exists after your function return a pointer to it. (While the `str` variable goes out of scope, you are returning a copy of that `str` pointer, the pointer points to the start of a string literal that exists for the whole lifetime of the application).